# Making sure whether the test of goodness of fit was done correctly.

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, chi-squared

The Elves Toy Co.  manufactures toy trains. For quality control  purpose it checks 5 random trains from production line . The probability that a train is defective and is thrown away=$0.25$. The number of trains thrown away vs the number of weeks in which that amount of trains were thrown is given in the picture.[image]. Propose an appropriate probability distribution and check for its correctness. Sorry I dont know how to make table :(. $$\text {Attempt} $$. This distribution  has to be discrete as number of discarded trains have to integers. Now I think this has to be binomial as poisson is for large number of data set. Thus I got $ E_{i }$ for  each number of trains as $12,21,14,5,1,0$ . I  then clube last three columns as $\text E_{i} $ has to $\geq 5$. Then $\chi $ came out to be $0.5$ . Now $\chi_{0.05}$ for $3$ df is $7.8$ as this is greater than calculated one thus our test holds good and the distribution is binomial. I am still not able to convince myself thoroughly that its true. Am I correct or am I missing something? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course, the 'observed counts' $10, 21, 14, \dots$ for 'categories'
$0, 1, 2, \dots$ are integers. But it is incorrect to round 'expected counts'
to integers; perhaps they can be rounded to a couple of decimal places.

My four expected counts for categories $0, 1, 2, 3^+$ are
$12.34, 20.57, 13.71,  5.38, $ respectively. And my chi-squared statistic is $ 0.945 < 7.815,$
so I do not reject the null hypothesis that the number of defective trains
 out of 5 inspected each week is distributed as $\mathsf{Binom}(5, .25).$

Data are "consistent with" this binomial model. However, the same
data might also be consistent with other similar models. (So one
should not declare that $\mathsf{Binom}(5, .25)$ is ***the*** correct
model.)

Comment: How did you calculate those $Ei's $? Both of our expected frequencies have significant difference.

Comment: You Commented before I proofread. Typos fixed. BTW, what is the purpose of the fragment of a figure at the beginning of your Question (with 494)?

Comment: No its a different question. Thanks for the answer.